# How to create a defcustom variable that accepts only a vector of strings?

Tags: customize, defcustom

I am using `repeat` for now. But I don't know how to have the same for `vector`.

EDIT: I want **INS** and **DEL** options like in `repeat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:type` **`restricted-sexp`**.  It accepts a Lisp value that must fit the **`:match-alternatives`** restriction that you specify -- in this case that the value must satisfy `vectorp` and each of the vector's elements must satisfy `stringp`.

```el
   (defcustom foo ["a" "bb" "ccc"]
     "Foo's doc."
     :type  '(restricted-sexp :tag "Vector"
              :match-alternatives
              (lambda (xs) (and (vectorp xs) (seq-every-p #'stringp xs))))
     :group 'convenience)
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Composite Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html).

---

If you want to specify a *fixed vector length* then you can use a `:type` of `(vector string string string)` etc. instead.

---

If `restricted-sexp` doesn't satisfy you (e.g., because you don't get `INS` and `DEL` buttons) then you can define your own custom type - see (elisp) [Defining New Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-New-Types.html).

---

Another possibility, if you really want `INS` and `DEL` buttons, is to define the option value as a list, using `repeat`, and then in your code that uses it convert to a vector.  In that case, be sure to use `:set` with `defcustom` (with a setter that converts the new list value to a vector), so that whenever someone customizes the value you reconvert list to vector.

When I say "convert", I mean that you would have the option for a list value and a *separate, internal variable* for that list value converted to a vector. Users would see `INS` and `DEL` in Customize, and would thus configure a list value, but you would have a `:set` function on the `defcustom` which would both (1) set the option value according to the user's edit (as usual, using the default setter function) and (2) set the internal variable's value to the new value of the option, after converting that new list value to a vector.

For example:

```el
(defcustom my-opt '("a" "bb" "ccc")
  "`my-opt's doc."
  :type  '(repeat string)
  :group 'convenience
  :set  (lambda (sym defs)
         (custom-set-default sym defs)
         (setq my-var  (vconcat my-opt))))

(defvar my-var [] "`my-var's doc.")
```

---

In sum, `repeat` is only for lists, and it is the only predefined `defcustom` `:type` construct that gives you `INS` and `DEL` buttons. The doc explicitly calls out these buttons in its description of `repeat`.

Comment: I am getting a `STANDARD. (mismatch)` in customize buffer. And it doesn't show INS and DEL options like in `repeat`.

Comment: I corrected the predicate; please try again. No, you won't get INS and DEL - you get a single sexp field to edit. (You added wanting to have INS and DEL after you posted the question.)

Comment: Where do I find `repeat` widget's definition?

Comment: You find it in standard library `wid-edit.el`:

`(define-widget 'repeat 'editable-list
  "A variable length homogeneous list."
  :tag "Repeat"
  :format "%{%t%}:\n%v%i\n")`